# MySQL search for keywords containing apostrophe or not

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database containing a list of UK towns and one of which is "Connah's Quay".

I want to be able to return results for "Connah's Quay" whether I have used the apostrophe or not, so "Connah's Quay" and "Connahs Quay" returns "Connah's Quay".

Rather than creating a field containing both versions (one with and another without the apostrophe), is there a SQL query I can run that will return results whether I have used the apostrophe or not?

QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes WHERE postal_town LIKE "connahs%";
```

Comment: sure but that will depend on what your query presently looks like, or have you not one made up yet? You could use LIKE or a regexp.

Comment: `LIKE "connah%";` - remove the `s`.

Comment: I have added the query, thanks.

Comment: I added something above yours

Comment: You could use the replace function on the search term and the column to remove all single quotes from both in the where clause.

Comment: @SloanThrasher, can you provide an example please?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes WHERE postal_town LIKE 'connah%'"` if you don't want to REPLACE anything.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes WHERE replace(postal_town,char(39),'') like 'replace('connahs%',char(39),'');` I think.  but I believe this will destroy index use.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that doesn't cater for cases where I have specifically included the full thing, i.e. "connahs"

Comment: you've a few answers below now.

Comment: *"that doesn't cater for cases where I have specifically included the full thing, i.e. "connahs""* - Why wouldn't it? `LIKE "connah%"` should work for both instances.

Comment: Yes, but "connahs%" would not. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard approach would be to normalise the data and search on that, so something like:

```
SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes WHERE REPLACE(postal_town, '''', '') LIKE 'connahs%';
```

This is a bit horrible to do on the fly (and not index friendly), so you would be better to store on table (also means you can also then cope with "Stow-cum-Quy" vs. "Stow cum Quy", etc.)

Comment: That works, but I see what you mean by not index friendly. Could you explain what you mean by store on table please?

Comment: Have another column with the normalised data (or better still, have another table for the "good" version of the town name, and have a foreign key to that; assuming you're trying to search user generated data)

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM uk_postcodes 
WHERE REPLACE(postal_town,"'","") LIKE CONCAT(REPLACE("connah's","'",""),"%");
```

This removes the apostrophes from both the search term and the column value before the comparison.